# Arrows to place around the bullets

Tags: javascript, navigation

I have a slider with pagination as dots as well as navigation with arrows. I would like to place the arrows around the dot navigation as here in the image attached below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aT0zV.png)

Initially I did this with CSS but it does not look good at all and keeps changing and shifting on different screens.

DOT HTML

```
    <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-clickable swiper-pagination-bullets swiper-pagination-horizontal">
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 1"></span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 2"></span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 3"></span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 4"></span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet swiper-pagination-bullet-active" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 5" aria-current="true"></span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 6"></span>
<span class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 7"></span></div>
```

Arrow HTMl

```
<div class="elementor-swiper-button elementor-swiper-button-prev" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Previous slide" aria-controls="swiper-wrapper-4710f9d6dce1fd1c3" aria-disabled="false">
<i aria-hidden="true" class="eicon-chevron-left"></i> <span class="elementor-screen-only">Previous</span>
</div>
<div class="elementor-swiper-button elementor-swiper-button-next" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Next slide" aria-controls="swiper-wrapper-4710f9d6dce1fd1c3" aria-disabled="false">
<i aria-hidden="true" class="eicon-chevron-right"></i> <span class="elementor-screen-only">Next</span>
</div>
```

I tried this

```
  <script>
      function insertAfter(referenceNode, newNode) {
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
      }
      let elem = document.getElementByClassName("swiper-pagination");
      let div = document.getElementByClassName("elementor-swiper-button-next");
      insertAfter(div, elem);
    </script>
```

But it doesnt seem to work. I am quite new with JS. Could someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one (hacky) way you can do it with jQuery, though it does come with a side-effect:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper", {
        pagination: {
            clickable: false, /* Can't have nice things */
            el: '.swiper-pagination',
        },
        navigation: {
            nextEl: ".elementor-swiper-button-next",
            prevEl: ".elementor-swiper-button-prev"
        },
        on: {
            init: function () {
                // Scope the navigation button selection to the current Swiper instance
                var $pagination = $(this.el).find('.swiper-pagination');
                var $nextButton = $(this.el).find('.elementor-swiper-button-next');
                var $prevButton = $(this.el).find('.elementor-swiper-button-prev');

                // Prepend the prev button and append the next button to the pagination container
                $pagination.prepend($prevButton);
                $pagination.append($nextButton);
            },
        }
    });
});
```

The way it works is it finds and moves the buttons inside the swiper-pagination div. Wrapping it in the on: init method makes sure the code is only executed after the slider has been initialized.

As for the side-effect: Note that the next/prev buttons inside the pagination wrapper appear to mess up the index of the bullets, meaning that clicking bullet #1 will activate slide #2. This is why the bullets in my example cannot be clicked. I'll update this answer if I happen to find a fix for this, but since the bullets not being clickable just so happens to be default behavior for Swiper it might not matter to you.

You'll probably need to reset some of the base CSS styles for the buttons so that they are not positioned outside of the document flow:

```
.elementor-swiper-button-next,
.elementor-swiper-button-prev {
    position: static;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Here's a codepen](https://codepen.io/appel/pen/ZEZLBON) illustrating it.